# How can I configure the smtp port used by Accounts.ui in Meteor

Tags: meteor, smtp, cloud9-ide, meteor-accounts

I am unable to send email in development because cloud9 blocks normal smtp ports. Can I configure Accounts.ui in Meteor to use mailgun's special smtp port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with an environment variable like this

```
MAIL_URL = "smtp://user%40gmail.com:password@smtp.googlemail.com:465"
```

The first @ has to be written as %40 - to do with the way the url is parsed